# PDFKIT over-flow data goes to newpage for each row

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I have a function that generates a row of data depending on an array. Works perfectly fine for the first page but as soon as the data is overflowed somewhere around `doc.text("exmaple",70,560)` When the Y coordinate is set to 560 it goes to next page. But further to that the next iteration should result into `doc.text("example2,70,600)` goes into 3rd page and 4th page for the next item and so on. This behaviour is not expected as it should create a new row in the second page. Full code is listed below. I am not expert at JS and node so maybe making some silly mistake. The issue starts at around the 10th item of array or y coordinate being 560 as mentioned above

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({
    layout: 'landscape'
});
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));

const productCodes = ['JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614','JD100979758','JD4010069','JD5879085','JD7515824','JD7517614']
function generateDexTable(doc,product){
    let i,
    invoiceTableTop= 160;
        for(let i = 0;i<product.length;i++){
            const item = product[i]
            const position = invoiceTableTop+(i*40);
            doc.text(item,70,position)
        }
}
generateDexTable(doc,productCodes)
```

I have genuinely created a redundant array to simulate this error. This creates a pdf output of 26 pages where expected is much less. I want essentially to create a kind of invoice via this kit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify this by using the default height for the text-blocks and `moveDown()`:

```
function generateDexTable(doc, product) {

    for (let i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
        const item = product[i];
        doc.text(item);
        doc.moveDown(3); // you can adjust this to get the desired margins between text blocks
    }
    doc.end();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank-you so much for your response. Works like a charm :)